# Grounding for exterior cable/phone interface boxes

Tags: grounding, coaxial-cable, telephone

I have a cable and phone (currently unused) media boxes on the outside of the house to which the service is connected from the alley aerially. The picture does not show the conduit that goes between the phone box (right) because it's been removed for painting but it should be there between the box and the wall elbow.

These are both plastic boxes. Do they need to be grounded? I do have a ground wire nearby but would prefer not to use it if they don't need to be.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the coax cable has a splitter that can be grounded, you could attach a ground to that directly. Some telco boxes have grounding lugs inside them that connect to protectors that will burn open if high voltage gets on your tele/internet line. I wouldn't ground the boxes themselves and not the cable coming in. Someone else can weigh in if they want, there's some pretty smart people on here.